# Format a number to string with custom separator?

Tags: java, formatting

I would like to format large numbers with an underscore as separator. I had hoped that `String.format` or `DecimalFormat` could be used. 
Example:

```
int number = 1234567;
String str1 = String.format("%,d", number);
System.out.println(str1);  // out puts  1,234,567
```

but changing comma with underscore

```
String str = String.format("%_d", number);
```

causes an exception

> UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '_'

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#_###");
String str2 = decimalFormat.format(number);
System.out.println(str2); // out puts 1234567_
```

Desired out put 1_234_567

Comment: 1. Format the number as a string with a comma separator. 2. Replace ',' with '_'.

Comment: @rossum How stupid of me not to think of it myself. Get it working with `String.format("%,d", number).replace('.', '_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for more information. You have to set the separator to "_" on your formatter object. For example:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('_');
    symbols.setGroupingUsed(true);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#######", symbols);
    df.setGroupingSize(3);

    String out = df.format(1234567);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed the right answer i was looking for, as i was wanting to apply a strange format to a number and the answers in the "duplicate" did not cover my issue. With `symbols.setGroupingSeparator('_'); symbols.setDecimalSeparator('|'); ` and `new DecimalFormat("####,###.##", symbols);` now i am able to output something like `12_345|67` for the input of `12345.67`